# Unable to install Kubernetes Latest version following the official installation guide on CentOS 7 on a VM

Tags: kubernetes, centos7

When I execute the following commands (taken from the official installation guide for kubernetes), the output is unexpected (shown below: )
Command (On CentOS 7):

```
cat < /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo
[kubernetes]
name=Kubernetes
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg 
https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
exclude=kube*
EOF
setenforce 0
yum install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
systemctl enable kubelet && systemctl start kubelet
```

Output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

base: centos.sonn.com
extras: mirror.sesp.northwestern.edu
updates: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
kubernetes/signature | 454 B 00:00:00
kubernetes/signature | 1.4 kB 00:00:00 !!!
kubernetes/primary | 33 kB 00:00:00
kubernetes 237/237
No package kubelet available.
No package kubeadm available.
No package kubectl available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

What you expected to happen:

kubeadm, kubeclt and kubelet get installed and are enabled

How to reproduce it:

Run the above mentioned commands on centos 7 (by following the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/)

```
Docker version: Client:
Version: 17.03.2-ce
API version: 1.27
Go version: go1.7.5
Git commit: f5ec1e2
Built: Tue Jun 27 02:21:36 2017
OS/Arch: linux/amd64
```

Server:

```
Version: 17.03.2-ce
API version: 1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
Go version: go1.7.5
Git commit: f5ec1e2
Built: Tue Jun 27 02:21:36 2017
OS/Arch: linux/amd64
Experimental: false
```

Environment:

Kubernetes version (use kubectl version): Unable to install the latest version following the official guide.
hardware configuration: Vertual machine as per the guidelines on the official guide(2GB ram and 2 CPUs)
OS:

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

Kernel:

```
Linux k1 3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jul 16 16:29:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be missing `<<EOF` at the end of the first line.

Also, I can see there is a **mistake** in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/).

Line containing `exclude=kube*` should be removed.

It should be as follows:

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo
[kubernetes]
name=Kubernetes
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
EOF
setenforce 0
yum install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
systemctl enable kubelet && systemctl start kubelet
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me after removing following line from the *kubernetes.repo*:

exclude=kubelet kubeadm kubectl

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo cat <<EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo
[kubernetes]
name=Kubernetes
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg 
https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
EOF
bash: /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo: Permission denied
```

After running this, I was still getting a permission denied error even tho I'm using sudo and my user account has admin rights. The solution to my issue was to login my Rocky Linux as the root user and finish the install.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the same exact issue that OP was having.

Answer (score 0):

use the sudo in front of /etc/
sudo cat < sudo /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).